# Draw a stratified sample of certain size in R

Tags: r

So I have a dataset and I'd like to split it into Active/Control group in stratified manner with regards to probability of certain event (5 groups).

In the first step, I draw 100 random samples per group:

```
library(plyr)
sample <- ddply(DF,.(prob_group),function(x) x[sample(nrow(x),100),])

table(sample$prob_group)

Output:
0-2 02-04 04-06 06-08   08- 
100   100   100   100   100
```

Afterwards, in the second step, I split the sample into two groups of an equal size in a stratified manner:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
out2 <- sample %>%
  group_by('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 
           'X6', 'X7', 'X8','X9', 'prob_group') %>%
  sample_n(250)
active <- out2

control <- subset(sample, !(sample$client_id %in% active$client_id))
```

However now I dont have 50 people in every group.

**I understand why, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to tell R that I want to keep the size same.**

```
table(active$prob_group)    
0-2 02-04 04-06 06-08   08- 
45    51    56    49    49 

table(control$prob_group)  
0-2 02-04 04-06 06-08   08- 
55    49    44    51    51
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close to the solution:

```
library(dplyr)
group_n <- 5
group_size <- 100

df <- data.frame(group=sample(rep(1:group_n,group_size)))
table(df$group)

active <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% sample_n(group_size/2)
table(active$group)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but when you do `group_by(group)`, you stratified only by one column. And i need the stratification with respect to other columns, not only to the 'group' variable.

Comment: I assumed the inclusion of the other columns was a mistake - because you seem to have very few samples only for so many stratification variables. It also seems to me your sampling code should not even run without `replace=TRUE`.

But the solution would then be to have `replace=FALSE` and the sample size equal to whatever very small amount of samples you would end up with in each combination of variable levels.

Comment: I know its small sample for that many attributes. The main goal is to have 50 persons per `prob_group` in both groups. The stratification is something nice-to-have and I am well aware it will be only an approximation. Where should I put the `replace=FALSE`?

Comment: as an argument to `sample_n`; but it should be the default really. I'm not very positive that you will be able to though; it seems entirely possible here that some combinations of variable levels have no samples at all, so that makes it impossible to have an equal number everywhere.

Comment: I know, i tried and I got similar structure, but not completely stratified. Which is good enough for my purposes.